# Where should I place validation code that requires access to database?

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, controller

I have a Spring MVC webpage that is used for password resets. This requires us to do the following validation workflow:

1. provide username OR email
2. if email is provided make sure it is valid format (ex: @Email)
3. Check that User exists by:

   3a) Trying to load the user from the database via username
   3b) if loading by username returns `null`, try to load the user from the database via email
4. After loading, check that user is not locked out: `user.isLocked()`

Currently I have all of these Validations inside a `org.springframework.validation.Validator`

However this requires my Validator to have access to the `UserService` object so it can load users. This causes the user to be loaded 2x, once by my validator and a second time by my `Controller` so it can invoke `.resetPassword(User)`.

---

Question: Where should I be checking item #3 ?

Are those validations better suited for the Controller ? If I leave validation as is, can I return the User from the Validator (it has `void` method due to Validator interface)?

Comment: Do you have a separate dao layer that your service layer calls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, steps 3 and 4 don't belong to view layer (in particular, to validation performed by controller) at all.

These steps are essential parts of business logic for this scenario, therefore they should be implemented in service layer.

Your service layer should provide a method such as

```
public void resetPasswordByUsernameOrEmail(String usernameOrEmail) { ... }
```

and these steps should happen inside this method, along with `resetPassword(User)`.

If you need, you can make controller aware of result of this method by throwing an exception, returning a `boolean` or an `enum` (if you want to distinguish between different error conditions).

Answer (score 2):

**To answer your questions in order:**

1. You should do the checking for a User's existence in the **UserDao**.
2. **No**, these validations should not be in the Controller.  The Controller shouldn't know anything about validation, otherwise it would be trying too do to much and we'd be guilty of *low cohesion*.
3. Since you're using an interface that defines a method with a void return, if you wanted to return a User you would have to do one of the following:

   - **Create your own method** in your Validator implementation.  The disadvantage of this is that you could not use polymorphism as effectively since you would depend on a method not defined in the Interface.
   - **Make your own Validator** (possibly make your own Interface that extends Spring's Validator interface and defines the method you want).  This is probably what I would choose.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's a duplicate: [Spring MVC Bean Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10288698/spring-mvc-bean-validation)

Another solution would be this:

In one of the projects I worked, we used to have a SpringBeanUtil class. It would get the WebApplicationContext, and get the bean needed through a static method.
It's kind of ugly, but helped on these kind of problems.

Use at you own risk.

```
public class SpringBeanUtil implements ApplicationContextAware{

private static ApplicationContext APPLICATION_CONTEXT;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        throws BeansException {
    APPLICATION_CONTEXT=applicationContext;
}

public static Object getBean(String name){
    return APPLICATION_CONTEXT.getBean(name);
}
public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> type){
    return APPLICATION_CONTEXT.getBean(type);
}
}
```