# Spring MVC validator: validate using current session object

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I want to validate my MyAccount form using a custom Spring `Validator`.

Basic validation rules are no problem.

I now have this requirement, which seems pretty obvious and common:

If the user (currently logged in) changes his username, I'll have to check if it's already in use. If it's not been changed, I'm fine (it would definitely be in use when checked, that's why I don't want to check it in that case). The problem is, that the validator is a Spring managed Singleton and I don't seem to have access to the current session (where I store my login context - i.e. not Spring Security). But I need the currently logged in user, in order to compare its e-mail with the one entered in the form.

This is my scenario, but the question is actually about how to validate using an object from the user's session, in general.

The ways I was thinking about solving this:

1. Do only basic validation in the `Validator` and do the rest, that I need the session for, in the `Controller`. Doesn't seem to be a nice solution.

   ```
       @RequestMapping(value="/myaccount", method=RequestMethod.GET)
       public String myAccount(@Valid MyAccountForm form, BindingResult result, HttpSession session)
       {
          boolean hasUsernameChanged = // check using session
          if (hasUsernameChanged && CustomerService.customerAlreadyExists(form.getUsername()))
             result.rejectValue("username", "my.error.code");

          if (result.hasErrors()) {
             // handle errors
          } else {
             // proceed
          }
       }
   ```
2. Adding a second validate method to the `Validator` like so

   ```
   public void validateWithCurrentCustomer(Customer current) {
     ...
   }
   ```

   and call it explicitly from the controller, with the appropriate object. Not much better, but at least the validation logic is in one class, although separated in two methods, one of which is not standard.
3. Not having the `Validator` a Spring managed (singleton) bean, but create it everytime in the initBinder method. Instead of:

   ```
   @Autowired
   public MyAccountController(MyAccountFormValidator validator)
   {
       this.validator = validator;
   }
   @InitBinder
   protected void initBinder (WebDataBinder binder)
   {
       binder.setValidator(validator);
   }
   ```

   do

   ```
   @InitBinder
   protected void initBinder (WebDataBinder binder, HttpSession session)
   {
       Customer current = ...// get from session
       binder.setValidator(new MyAccountFormValidator(current));
   }
   ```

But here, the problem is, that since the validator is not Spring managed, it's hard to get a service (like CustomerService) injected into the validator, for checking if an e-mail is available or not.

Am I missing something, any other ways to achieve what I want? This seems to be a common problem, but I couldn't find any pattern on Google or SO.

Thanks for your hints.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to access any Spring bean from your validator. Maybe this answer can help. 
[Where should I place validation code that requires access to database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767487/where-should-i-place-validation-code-that-requires-access-to-database/18767893#18767893)

Basically, you can make a SpringBeanUtil singleton, which gives you access to any bean you want.

Comment: Is your answer based on my thought #3? I already have such a helper, which I marked as deprecated to tell developers that this should not be done. I only want to use it for legacy code, that can't be turned into Spring code at the moment.